# Python *.exe file from *.py

Tags: python, exe, py2exe

I've a python project split in 3 files : main.py, file1.py and file2.py From this files I've generated a *.exe file (main.exe) but when I start the executable file I receive the error :

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
   File "win32com\client\gencache.pyc", line 649, in Rebuild
   File "win32com\client\gencache.pyc", line 65, in _SaveDicts
   File "win32com\client\gencache.pyc", line 141, in GetGeneratePath
   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\dir1\\Python\\dir2\\test\\version\\dist\\library.zip\\ win32com\\gen_py\\__init__.py'
```

In my main.py I've :

```
import win32com.client

if win32com.client.gencache.is_readonly == True:
   win32com.client.gencache.is_readonly = False
   win32com.client.gencache.Rebuild()
```

but also with these rows of code I'm not able to solve the problem. Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating an empty `__init__.py`?

Comment: How do you generate exe file?

Comment: Hi.
cddrake : How add a empty  __init__.py file should  solve the problem ?
Mikko Ohtamaa :  I've used py2exe to generate  *.exe

Comment: My _guess_ is that the executable is attempting to import your files.  In order for Python to allow that, you usually have to create a _package_.  You have to add in an empty file named (exactly) `__init__.py` in your directory, e.g. `gen_py\__init__.py`.  Try that, and re-build the executable.

Comment: Hi all,I've done a test with __init__.py empty file but without success.In any case I've try tu build *.exe with pyinstaller and..It works.Thanks for your help and have a nice day :)